# How to handle multiple users using CoreData

Tags: ios, authentication, core-data, swift3

So I am creating an expense tracking app which allows the users to create different wallets. Each wallet has it's own expenses and also have a password to access it. However I want each wallet to have it's own expenses and not to be able to access the other account's expenses.

Almost like the eWallet app if you have it.

My question is, how can this be done using coreData. I have a data model for expenses which manages things like the expense name and date. But how do I make them unique to a single wallet. Do I have to create another entity of wallet and classify each expense into it and then retrieve accordingly, or is there a much better way to do this?

Also, should I be using CoreData or something like Firebase or Parse?

Answer (score 1):

Neither iOS nor Core Data has any sense of multiple users, so you need to implement your own solution. How you do it depends on things like how secure the data needs to be, whether the data is available from a server, and whether you can delete the logged-out user's data or if you need to keep it.

Probably the easiest way is to create one instance of your wallet object per user. All cards or expenses or whatever are related to an instance of that object. When someone logs in, reset the UI and get rid of existing data, then load the new user's wallet. You need to be sure to clear out all existing data from memory when someone logs in or you risk displaying a user's data to someone else.

Other possible approaches, depending on your requirements, include:

- Use separate persistent store files, one per user. Unload the persistent store and rebuild the entire Core Data stack.
- Delete the user's data when they log out. Later, retrieve it from a server (if you have one).